# Repeating pattern matching in Eclipse regexp

Tags: regex, eclipse

I'm trying to turn XML files in to SQL statements within Eclipse to save on the manual work of converting large files.

A line such as:

```
<TABLE_NAME COL_1="value1" COL_2="value2"/>
```

should be converted to:

```
insert into TABLE_NAME (COL_1, COL_2) values ("value1", "value2");
```

So far, I have managed to match and capture the table name and the first column/value pair with:

```
<(\w+)( \w+)=(".+?").*/>
```

The `.*` near the end is just there to test the first part of the pattern and should be removed once it is complete.

The following replace pattern yields the following result:

```
insert into $1 ($2) values ($3);
insert into TABLE_NAME ( COL_1) values ("value1");
```

The problem I'm having is that the number of columns is different for different tables, so I would like a generic pattern that would match *n* column/value pairs and repeatedly use the captured groups in the replace pattern. I haven't managed to understand how to do this yet although `\G` seems to be a good candidate.

Ideally, this would be solved in a single regexp statement, though I also wouldn't be against multiple statements that have to be run in sequence (though I really don't want to have to force the developer to execute once for every column/value pair).

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: in my experience it is better to use XSLT to convert XML. I doubt you can solve this with a single regex but you can probably go a long way with a simple java program and multiple regexes (one for the table and one of the columns, going by your example)

Comment: @Benjamin Thanks for the tip. I'll have a look at XSLT. I've never used it before. I have experience in regexp and Perl, so my first reaction was to use that. It may not be the best tool to use in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I did not in the end solve this with regular expressions as originally envisaged. Taking alternative solutions in mind, it was solved in the end by re-factoring test code to make it re-usable and then co-opting [dbunit](http://www.dbunit.org/) to use tests to write data to the different stages of the development databases.

I know that this is a misuse of tests, but it does make the whole thing much simpler since the user gets a green/red feedback as to whether the data is inserted or not and the same test data can be inserted for manual acceptance tests as is used for the automated component/integration tests (which used dbunit with an in-memory database). As long as these fake test classes are not added to the test suite, then they are only executed by hand.

The resulting fake tests ended up being extremely simple and lightweight, for instance:

```
public class MyComponentTestDataInserter extends DataInserter {
  @Override
  protected String getDeleteSql() {
    return "./input/component/delete.sql";
  }

  @Override
  protected String getInsertXml() {
    return "./input/component/TestData.xml";
  }

  @Test
  public void insertIntoDevStage() {
    insertData(Environment.DEV);
  }

  @Test
  public void insertIntoTestStage() {
    insertData(Environment.TEST);
  }
}
```

This also had the additional advantage that a developer can insert the data in to a single environment by simply executing a single test method via the context menu in the IDE. At the same time, by running the whole test class, the exact same data can be deployed to all environments simultaneously.

Also, a failure at any point during data cleanup or insertion causes the whole transaction to be rolled back, preventing an inconsistent state.